# Wrong result of TIdURI.URLDecode when unit LazUTF8 is used

Tags: http, utf-8, indy, lazarus, freepascal

With Free Pascal 3.0.4, this test program correctly writes **ÄÖÜ**

```
program FPCTest;

uses IdURI;

begin
  WriteLn(TIdURI.URLDecode('%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C'));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

However if the unit LazUTF8 (as described [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Unicode_Support_in_Lazarus#Using_UTF-8_in_non-LCL_programs)) is used, it writes **???**

```
program FPCTest;

uses IdURI, LazUTF8;

begin
  WriteLn(TIdURI.URLDecode('%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C'));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

How can I fix this decoding error for programs which use LazUTF8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `String` type is an alias for `AnsiString` <sup>1</sup>, much of Indy's functionality exposes extra parameters/properties to let users control which ANSI encodings are used when `AnsiString` values are passed around in operations that perform `AnsiString<->byte` conversions.

<sup>1: Delphi pre-2009, and FreePascal/Lazarus when `{$ModeSwitch UnicodeStrings}` and `{$Mode DelphiUnicode}` are not used (FYI, Indy 11 will use them!).</sup>

In most cases, Indy's default byte encoding is ASCII (because many of the Internet protocols that Indy implements originally supported only ASCII - individual Indy components upgrade themselves to UTF as appropriate per protocol), though some things use the OS default codepage/charset instead.

Indy's default byte encoding can be changed at runtime by setting the global `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit, eg:

```
GIdDefaultTextEncoding := encUTF8;
```

But, in this particular situation, `TIdURI.URLEncode()` does not use `GIdDefaultTextEncoding`, but it does have an optional `ADestEncoding` parameter that you can use to specify a specific byte encoding for the returned `AnsiString` (in addition to an optional `AByteEncoding` parameter to specify the byte encoding of the parsed url octets - UTF-8 by default), eg:

```
TIdURI.URLDecode('%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C'
  {$IFNDEF FPC_UNICODESTRINGS}, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8{$ENDIF}
)
```

The above will parse the url-encoded octets as UTF-8, and then return that data as-is in a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString`.

If you do not specify an output encoding for `ADestEncoding`, `URLDecode()` defaults to the OS default.  If you want it to use `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` instead, specify `IndyTextEncoding_Default` in the `ADestEncoding` parameter:

```
TIdURI.URLDecode('%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C'
  {$IFNDEF FPC_UNICODESTRINGS}, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8, IndyTextEncoding_Default{$ENDIF}
)
```

Another option would be to use the `IndyTextEncoding(CodePage)` function for `ADestEncoding`, passing it FreePascal's [`DefaultSystemCodePage`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/defaultsystemcodepage.html) variable, which the `LazUtils` package sets to `CP_UTF8` <sup>2</sup>:

```
TIdURI.URLDecode('%C3%84%C3%96%C3%9C'
  {$IFNDEF FPC_UNICODESTRINGS}, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8, IndyTextEncoding(DefaultSystemCodePage){$ENDIF}
)
```

<sup>2: I have [opened a ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/246) in Indy's issue tracker to add support for `DefaultSystemCodePage` when compiling for FreePascal/Lazarus.</sup>

Comment: Geat suggestion, many thanks! I changed `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.DecodeAndSetParams` line 1910 according the last option to `Params.Add(TIdURI.URLDecode(s,{$IFDEF FPC_UNICODESTRINGS}LEncoding{$ELSE}IndyTextEncoding_UTF8, IndyTextEncoding(DefaultSystemCodePage){$ENDIF}));` to return form parameters using UTF-8, works wonderfully

Comment: @mjn42 I'll look into incorporating something similar into the official code so it will work for both Delphi and FreePascal

Answer (score 0):

With this change in TIdURI.URLDecode lines 386ff LazUTF8 can be used:

```
  {$IFDEF FPC}
  Result := string(AByteEncoding.GetString(LBytes));
  {$ELSE}
  {$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}
  EnsureEncoding(ADestEncoding, encOSDefault);
  CheckByteEncoding(LBytes, AByteEncoding, ADestEncoding);
  SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(LBytes), Length(LBytes));
  {$ELSE}
  Result := AByteEncoding.GetString(LBytes);
  {$ENDIF}
  {$ENDIF}
```

---

**Notes**

This change assumes that the LazUTF8 unit is used *always*, and the Indy source code change needs to be applied every time when a new version is used.

Also I found no way to fix the TIdURI.URLDecode in a way which works with and without LazUTF8.

Comment: The problem with this patch is that it prevents `URLDecode()` from utilizing the `ADestEncoding` parameter if the caller wants to use a specific output encoding. At the very least, I would suggest moving the `{$IFDEF FPC}` code inside the `{$IFDEF STRING_IS_ANSI}` block, and only when `ADestEncoding=nil`. Alternatively, maybe patch the `TIdMBCSEncoding.Create` constructor instead in the `IdGlobal` unit to use `FreePascal`'s `DefaultSystemCodePage` rather than `CP_ACP`, and don't patch `URLDecode()` itself at all.

Comment: "*I found no way to fix the TIdURI.URLDecode in a way which works with and without LazUTF8*" - see the answer I posted.